# Moving search to navigation section Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, search, navigation

Currently, I have this code in my default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

I'd like to move the search bar within the `<nav>` inside `topmenu.html` but I'm unsure of how to do that.

I tried `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>` but that doesn't work.

Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add search block inside navigation block.

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml" />
</block>
```

Comment: oOOO okies, now I understand. But it seems when adding anything within the nav block, in mobile view, the navigation no longer function the same. In that, the navigation stays on the page vs hidden until you hit the hamburger icon and it slides in from the left. Any idea how I can how keep that function with the search bar in there?

Comment: Above code working for desktop ?

Comment: it is working for desktop yes. Just not right for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this xml code in yout theme.xml:

```
<move element="top.search" destination="page.top" after="catalog.topnav" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but I had to add the actual top search block into my xml. It wasn't already existing where I can just move it if that makes any sense.